# How to render the html file in react js along with a supportive folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a static html file along with a supportive js files in a folder named as data. The folder(data) contains two js files, 3 png files and one sub folder for fonts. the fonts folder contains 3 font files.
[image: The image added shows the folder structure]. Now I want to render the html file in react app.

```
class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.html = require('../assessment/1_2_1/index.html');
    }
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.html }} />
        );
    }
}
```

This code renders the html file. but the data folder is not accessed. Hence i am not getting the desired page. 
How to import the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` should not be used for this use case. I suggest you use a server side rendering framework like Razzle or Next.js. Put your assets(images, fonts, css) etc in a static folder and react component js in pages folder(in case of Next.js)